# C# .NET Dynamic Trailing Zeroes?

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing a library to format numbers. There is an issue where the number of trailing zeroes needs to be specified. An example of this is financial data where some prices are shown with more than 2 decimal places but only the first two decimal places can be trailing zeroes.

Examples (Given 2 trailing zeroes and precision 4):

0.10000 => 0.10

0.11100 => 0.111

0.119 => 0.119

0.11119 => 0.1112

I also want to use this in conjunction with the "P" and "C" formatting provided by System.Globalization. Examples:

0.587 "C" => $0.587

0.20  "C" => $0.20

0.20001 "C" => $0.20

0.48745 "C" => $0.4875

or

0.587 "P" => 58.70%

0.20  "C" => 20.00%

0.20001 "C" => 20.00%

0.48745 "C" => 48.745%

I want to be able to provide a variable number of trailing zeroes to the library.

I want to utilize the built in functionality so I can leverage globalization. Since .ToString and String.Format allows specifying the number of decimal places to show, I figured I could use some fancy logarithmic math to determine whether the decimal place should be displayed or not. I figured I would see if there is a better solution.

Comment: I want to have dynamic trailing zeroes in conjunction with the percent and currency formatting provided by System.Globalization. I am well aware that "0.00##" will put the first two decimal places as trailing zeroes but, as far as I can tell, it won't support the "P" or the "C".

Comment: Is there anything your library will do that .Format and .ToString aren't capable of?

Comment: @ReacherGilt It is an internal library for my work which will normalize how things are formatted. It also provides support for magnitudes, colorizing, data validation, null handling, and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a short algorithm that will spit out the appropriate precision. This can be used in conjunction with "PX", "NX", or "CX" for use with globalization and the built in .ToString formatting. It has been unit tested with a variety of numbers so it is robust.

```
    /// <summary>Calculate the correct precision based on trailing zeroes and target precision
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="number">the number to check (multiply by 100 if it is being formatted as a percent)</param>
    /// <param name="trailingZeroes">the number of trailing zeroes</param>
    /// <param name="precision">the number of decimal places to show</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Argument Exception: trailing zero and precision cannot be less than one or greater than 99
    /// Argument Exception: trailing zeros cannot be larger than the precision
    /// </returns>
    private int CalculatePrecision(double number, int trailingZeroes, int precision)
    {
        if (trailingZeroes < 0 || trailingZeroes > 99 || precision < 0 || precision > 99)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Trailing Zeroes and precision must be between 0 and 99.");
        }

        // make sure trailng zeroes is not larger than precision
        trailingZeroes = Math.Min(trailingZeroes, precision);

        // a temporary value for locating decimal places
        double tempValue;

        // just the decimal places
        double allDecimalPlaces = number - Math.Floor(number);

        // the individual decimal place at a given power of 10
        double singleDecimalPlaceValue;

        // search for the zeroes in the decimal places
        for (int i = precision; i > trailingZeroes; i--)
        {
            // get just the decimal place that needs to be checked
            tempValue = allDecimalPlaces * Math.Pow(10, i - 1);
            singleDecimalPlaceValue = Math.Round((tempValue - Math.Floor(tempValue)) * 10);

            // check for a 0 decimal or a 10 value (for floating point math)
            if (singleDecimalPlaceValue != 0 && singleDecimalPlaceValue != 10)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        // if all zeroes are found, return trailing zeroes
        return trailingZeroes;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
number.ToString("0.00##")
```

and

```
decimal.Parse(text)
```

for example

```
var inputs = new[] { "0.1000", "0.11100", "0.119", "0.11119" };

var numbers = inputs.Select(decimal.Parse);

var output = numbers.Select(x => x.ToString("0.00##"));

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", output));
```

outputs

```
0.10, 0.111, 0.119, 0.1112
```

---

In terms of percentage and currency, I don't believe there is any clever way to do this, but the following can be combined with the above:

#### Currency

```
var symbol = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol // $
// ...
var output = numbers.Select(x => symbol + x.ToString("0.00##"));
// ...
```

#### Percentage

```
// ...
var numbers = inputs.Select(x => decimal.Parse(x) * 100);
// ...
```

Comment: If you use `"0.00##"` as your format string, you'll get the desired results without having to do any rounding or anything.

Comment: This doesn't address using .ToString() to get the percent and currency formatting provided by System.Globalization in conjunction with the dynamic trailing zero.

Comment: @ChrisPeterson Could you please update your question with a more clear explanation of what is required?

Comment: I added a comment, I don't know how to make it more clear, any suggestions?

Comment: @ChrisPeterson Example input/output would be great :)

Comment: Thanks for trying but the system.globalization provides a lot more functionality than just changing the currency symbol or multiplying the percentage. I think I'm going to have to use my fancy log math to figure it out. Your method will work for fixing the immediate problem, though.

Comment: There may be a solution out there. Not one I can think of off the top of my head though I am afraid! Best of luck.

Comment: I posted my own solution, let me know what you think.